# Is it possible to mount file to the docker container running in Google Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run

I have a docker image that I run in Google Cloud Run. The app inside the image needs a config file `/etc/app.conf`. In my image there is no such file.

When I run it local I can mount the config file from my computer inside the container:

```
docker run --detach --volume=`pwd`/app.conf:/etc/app.conf myimage
```

Is there a way to mount a file in Google Cloud Run?

(Now I'm just creating a new image based on my original image that has that file, but I would like to simplify this process)

Comment: Google Cloud Run does not support mounting volumes or file systems at this time in GA status. Good article with suggestions: https://medium.com/google-cloud/3-great-options-for-persistent-storage-with-cloud-run-f1581ee05164

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can cheat and mount this file in read only mode. The trick is to use Secret Manager.

- [Store your file in secret manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets)
- Load the [secret as volume](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets) in Cloud Run

The file is in read only, but it works.

However, keep in mind that you have [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/quotas):

- the file can't be larger 64KiB -> Large files aren't supported, but fit conf file.
- You are limited to 90k access per minute

And [cost associated](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/pricing):

- $0.06 per active secret version
- $0.03 per 10k read

Comment: Very cool. Can you add details about: cost about $3 per million requests; 64 KiB payload, quota 600 read requests per minute.